# Reduce Vendor.js file size in Angular 8

Tags: .net, angular, c#-3.0

I see few posts to reduce vendor.js file size in different angular versions. i.e. 2,4,6,7 but couldn't find any information specifically for Angular 8.

My Vendor.js file version is 10MB on initially project creation and due to that it is taking longer time to load production version. Is there a way to reduce this size?

Per my knowledge, I enable compression in angular.js file but no luck. My project is build using .net core 3.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please consider using `ng build -prod -aot -vc -cc -dop --buildOptimizer` to perform all the optimizations Angular provides. Note the `-vc` flag is meaning "vendor chunck" then your vendor will be splited into smallest chunck and be loaded in parallel by the client browser.

Comment: building project with this command reduce the bundle files but at the same time it is adding some random digits within filename. i.e. main.52ff59cbd141cff8ee1c.js. For me, this is issue as we are loading Angular within MVC application, I can not give exact script name to load inside my MVC application. Any suggestion for fix filename?

Comment: "namedChunks": true,in your angular.json configuration should do the job

Comment: that's not working, still creating file with random ids.

Comment: Try to add —output-hashing=false

Comment: yes adding that during build worked, here is the full command for other's reference: ng build --prod --output-hashing none --watch

Comment: --vendor-chunk is not recommended for production build as official documentation states